# Selenium IDE can't scroll a page by museOver or focus a locator but page does scrolled when click "Find" button

Tags: selenium, scroll, selenium-ide

I'm testing AJAX app using selenium IDE and got many problems on scrolling page.
Some elements can't be interacted with until they are visible.
I saw some articles on web mentioned this can be done by click/mouseOver/focus on the locator but all not working for me.
however, the page does scrolled when I click "Find" button on Selenium IDE to find the locator..
is there any way to simulate the click of Find button?
any suggestions are appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like by visible, you mean actually finished loading.  What you can do is for the element you want to interact with, put a command "waitForElementPresent" for the element:

```
waitForElementPresent | <elementid>
click | <elementid>
```

Thus, the test will wait for the element to be loaded before the interaction.

Klendathu